# Undo/Redo in WinForms using PostSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, postsharp

I know some approachs to add Undo/Redo features for WinForms controls, but I received an email from **PostSharp** about their **Aspect** tips showing the very basics to add Undo/Redo features, then I interested in this feature because seems very easy with minimal code source changes (and seems a robust approach because was made by **PostSharp** team).

Then, i would like to know whether **PostSharp** is capable to add undo/redo for a WinForm's control, lets say that for example I have a **ListBox** where I would like to add undo/redo capabilities for item removal using **PostSharp**, is that possible, how?.

I know much people loves **PostSharp** but I need to say that their documentation is very confuse and lacks of existential details, the official docs shows a undo/redo example for WPF using XAML, and thats all no information about other technologies, no mention about if it can be implemented in WinForms, so whats happens with people that do not uses WPF?, how I should do it?.

**PostSharp**'s Undo/Redo Documentation:

http://doc.postsharp.net/undoredo?utm_source=crm&utm_medium=email&utm_content=e4&utm_campaign=ln4

Comment: UnDo Item Add/Remove with the WinForms LB is not trivial.  To Remove, the user has to select an item which it is also typically what you want to have an UnDo-er watching.  Removing *several* items almost has to be in a transaction.  A plain Add is not too bad but Insert is problematic since it too requires the user to select an item for the insert point which in turn can screw up oreviously saved SelectedItems.  Then there is the case where the the LB does not *have* items but is bound (this seems to be what the Link docs handle BTW).

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, but the ListBox was a generic example, in the past you helped me to develop a undo/redo approach in other S.O. question which is the approach that I actually use, I just wanted to know more about PostSharps undo/redo feature to compare its beneffits if its possible to implement it in Winforms. thanks again.

Comment: A grown up version of that previous one will be on CodeProject soon.  We have no idea what is in the email code but the link appears to use injection code to watch a datasource. Plus it is WPF making it more apples vs pears.  Synching Add/Remove/SelectedItems with actual items and those actually in a DataSource is very problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postsharp isn't necessary. Basically, you'd need to create your own "breadcrumbs" and roll back and forth as needed. I've done this in the past by caching a copy of the screen's viewmodel for the past X number of user actions, then rebinding the UI to whatever version they want to roll back/forward to. This is a lot easier if you had built/organized the app with this in mind from the beginning, but I don't see why the same couldn't be done for the state of a listbox or user control. If you introduce a backing data-store this gets much more complicated and I would suggest transactions or changing the form so that nothing gets committed to the data-store until a 'Submit/Commit' type button is clicked, along with your own "breadcrumbs" to support undo/redo just for the editing session prior to submit.